# What is the fastest way of checking a encfs password?

Tags: security, password, encryption, disk-encryption, encfs

Is there any faster way of checking the password of an `encfs` folder than

```
echo <password> | encfs -S /root/.folder /root/folder
```

Answer (score 0):

That's as fast as it gets.

If you're making many attempts, you can speed this up a little by writing a program that checks passwords in a loop, to save the startup time on each attempt.

But [checking a password is inherently slow](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords), to keep brute force cracking attempts expensive.